# AngularJS pass Object onClick

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass object in `onClick` event. I'm getting alert like `[object Object]` I need inside data also.

View:

```
 <div ng-repeat="action in category.Actions">
    <a ng-click=" actionclick(action)"> {{action.Name}}</a>          
   </div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.actionclick = function (action) {
               alert("Option Name is " + action);
           };
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting alert like "[object Object]" I need inside data also.

Comment: alert is still alive?

Comment: you get `[object Object]` because you convert `action` to string.

Comment: What do mean by Alive? I'm seeing alert.

Comment: @user3194721 put this before all your scripts: `window.alert = function(){ console.log.apply(console,arguments) };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object in javascript outputs **[object Object]** when coerced into a string unless it's prototype overrides the native [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method.

the [plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) coerce all objects into strings if one of it's operands is of type string.

so these are equal:

```
("Option Name is " + action) === ("Option Name is " + action.toString())
```

To see the object itself use the console (developer tools):

```
console.log(action)
```

What you probably wanted to do is to reference the `name` property inside the object:

```
"Option Name is " + action.name
```

Comment: in addition, I think the intention was to have `ng-click="actionclick(action.name)"` instead of just `action`.